# Reuse captured group in RewriteCond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to setup a rewrite composed of 2 `RewriteCond` and one `RewriteRule` directives. The main purpose is to redirect all requests to `css`,`media` and `js` directories to correspondence subdomains. I have easily achieved it using 3 separate redirects, however I would like to be able to do it using just one.

I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(css|media|js)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^%1\.
RewriteRule ^(media|css|js)(/.+)$ http://$1.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2 [R=302,L]
```

However, it doesn't seem to allow the use of capturing group from first `RewriteCond` inside the other.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's working with back referencing from one `RewriteCond` to another, but you should be able to do:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/css|media|js
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^css|media|js\.
RewriteRule ^(media|css|js)(/.+)$ http://$1.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2 [R=302,L]
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have considered doing it this way, however this allows somebody to access `http://css.site.com/media` which is not desirable.